# Auto-skip properties not belonging to the type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have the following type declaration:

```
declare type Point2D = { x: number, y: number }
```

I fetch some data from the server and get the following:

```
const response = { x: 1.2, y: 3.4, foreign1: 'value', foreign2: 'value' }
```

Is it possible to automatically ignore all properties that do not belong to my type? Like this:

```
const point: Point2D = response // Should skip all props except for 'x' and 'y'
```

The important thing is that the reponse can have any number of foreign properties, so I cannot use object destructuring with the rest operator.

Comment: If you already know the properties you want why do you have to use the rest operator?

Comment: Short answer, no. You don't have information about the types at runtime, therefore you can't create a new object based on its properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Types aren't available at runtime.

In order to make things DRY, helper definition object can be used:

```
const Point2DDefinition = { x: 1, y: 1 };
type Point2D = typeof Point2DDefinition;

const point: Point2D = Object.entries(response)
.filter(([k]) => Object.keys(Point2DDefinition).includes(k))
.reduce((obj, [k, v]) => Object.assign(obj, { [k]: v }), {} as Point2D);
```

Because definition object relies on inferred type, it has certain limitations, e.g. intersection or union types cannot be used (a value cannot be a number and a string at the same time).

Notice that this code doesn't contain checks that `point` has all properties from `Point2D`, so technically it's more like `point: Partial<Point2D>`. It also doesn't check that values have same types as in definition.

Both checks can be additionally provided for type safety at runtime.

Alternatively, `Point2D` can be converted to a class that takes care of omitting unnecessary properties on construction.

Properties should be listed explicitly:

```
class Point2D {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor({ x, y }: Point2D) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Validation can be optionally added to class constructor for type safety at runtime.

A workaround for not listing properties explicitly would to combine a class with helper definition object to iterate over object properties. [Declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) can be used to assert that `Point2D` class has all properties that are listed in `Point2DDefinition`:

```
type TPoint2D = typeof Point2DDefinition;

interface Point2D extends TPoint2D {};
class Point2D {
    constructor(point: Point2D) {
        for (const k of Object.keys(Point2DDefinition)) {
            // runtime check for value types can also be added
            if (k in point) {
                this[k] = point[k];
            } else {
                throw new TypeError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The important thing is that the reponse can have any number of foreign properties, so I cannot use object destructuring with the rest operator.

Object destructuring results in WET but type-safe (at compilation time) code and certainly can be used for this purpose, for example:

```
const point: Point2D = (({ x, y }) => ({ x, y }))(response as Point2D);
```

It doesn't need the `...rest` of the properties because they are supposed to be discarded.