# typescript - cast json to an interface

Tags: json, typescript, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
export default interface IProject extends{
    Id?:number;
    name?:string;
    description?:string;
}
```

and I when get data from  the server the json file includes more properties like this:

```
{
    id,
    name,
    description,
    url,
    startDate,
    finishDate
}
```

but I only need the id, name and description fields. I tried this:

```
response.data.map((p: any) => p as IProject);
```

but the object includes the unnecessary data like url, startdate and finishDate
how can I map them correctly?
I know that we can map them like this:

```
response.data.map((p: any) => {
    return {id:p.id,name:p.name,description:p.description}
});
```

but is there any other better ways to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-skip properties not belonging to the type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378162/auto-skip-properties-not-belonging-to-the-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing what you're doing, but additionally adding some types for your server response as well. That way you get some intellisense for your mapping functions.

```
interface IProject {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
}

interface IProjectResponse {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
  url?: string;
  startDate?: string;
  finishDate?: string;
}

const mapResponse = (response: IProjectResponse[]) => response.data.map((p) => ({
  id: p.id,
  name:p.name,
  description: p.description,
}));

const response = await fetch(/* .. */);
const data = await response.json();

const projects: IProject[] = mapResponse(data);
```