# How to use TypeScript to map a large object to a smaller interface?

Tags: typescript, object, interface

I have an object returned from a server that contains e.g.

```
{
    lorem: 1,
    ipsa: [2,3],
    dolor: { sit: 'amet', consectetur: 'adipiscing'},
    elit: [{you: 'get'}, {the: 'picture'}]
}
```

and a TypeScript interface of

```
export interface smallerInterface {
    ipsa: number[];
    elit: any[];
}
```

I'm saving the returned object into IndexedDb, and don't want to save any fields that are not present on the interface.

I have tried casting `fullObject as smallerInterface` and `<smallerInterface>fullObject`, but when saving this object into the IndexedDb, it is still including the fields lorem and dolor.

How can I map the full object to this smaller interface (hopefully without writing an explicit map function) or otherwise force TypeScript to ignore these fields?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish.  What have you tried?  What doesn't work?  Is there a specific compiler error or runtime behavior you don't like?

Comment: Could you put this in context?

Comment: @jcalz updated.

Comment: You can't achieve this without writing code as far as I'm aware.. Either write a decorator that will manipulate your object, or write an adapter function/class. This cannot be done automagically otherwise, as TypeScript itself knows no such use cases.

Comment: @Lansana is correct.  TypeScript's type system is erased before being emitted to JavaScript, so nothing at runtime knows anything about `smallerInterface`... unless you tell it by, for example, making an array holding just the keys you care about.

Comment: That being said, I think your logic could be quite simple... change your `smallerInterface` from an `interface` to a `class`, and in your class constructor only copy the properties you want -- problem solved. Then just do `const smaller = new smallerInstance(largerInstance);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378162/auto-skip-properties-not-belonging-to-the-type-in-typescript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typescript types do not have a runtime impact and so casting an object to different types will have no tangible effect on that object at runtime.

One of the [goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#goals) of TypesScript:

> 9. Use a consistent, **fully erasable**, structural type system.

*emphasis added by me*

If you want to modify an object you need code beyond types to perform the modification. Given the inability to convert between values and types like you are looking for (see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13267) for further discussion), you will need to do something like:

```
export interface SmallerInterface {
    ipsa: number[];
    elit: any[];
}

export const smallerKeys = ['ipsa', 'elit'];

// Later once you have a result
const result = await makeRequest();
const reducedResult = smallerKeys.reduce((obj, key) =>
    ({ 
        ...obj, 
        [key]: result[key],
    }),
    {}
) as SmallerInterface;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have to break down a bigger object from API to Smaller classes. First of all I created smaller class using the same property name as the object from API.

```
export class SmallerClass {
    prop1: type,
    prop2: type,
    ...
   constructor(){
       // set default values to the props
   }
}
```

I use constructor to have an object with default values on creating an instance of the object.

```
let myObj = new SmallerClass();

let apiObj = `API Call`;
```

Then after receiving object from API, the instance of the `SmallerClass` can be instantiated using either of following methoods:
1. Using `key in Object` syntax

```
Object.keys(this.myObj).map((key) => {
   if (key in this.apiObj) {
      this.myObj [key] = this.apiObj[key];
   }
});
```

2. Using `hasOwnProperty`

```
Object.keys(this.myObj).map((key) => {
   if (this.apiObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.myObj[key] = this.apiObj[key];
   }
});
```