# Angular & RxJs : How to map json to Object Array

Tags: json, angular, rxjs

I try to map a Json http request answer to an object array (User) using RxJs :

My Json data looks like :

```
{"@context":"\/cotabe\/api\/contexts\/User","@id":"\/cotabe\/api\/users","@type":"hydra:Collection","hydra:member":[{"@id":"\/cotabe\/api\/users\/1","@type":"User","id":1,"email":"a.a@gmail.com","firstname":"Aaa","lastname":"Ggg","phone":"0606060606","mobile":"0606060607","fullName":"Aaa Ggg","username":"a.a@gmail.com","roles":["ROLE_DEVROOT","ROLE_USER"],"password":"$argon2i","createdAt":"-0001-11-30T00:00:00+01:00","updatedAt":"-0001-11-30T00:00:00+01:00","deleted":false}],"hydra:totalItems":1}
```

I would like to extract from that a User[], with user model :

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public email: string,
    public firstname: string,
    public lastname: string,
    public phone: string,
    public mobile: string,
    public roles: string[],
  ) {}
}
```

In my user service I have :

```
export class UserService {

  private users: User[] = [];
  userSubject = new Subject<User[]>();

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  emitUsers() {
    this.userSubject.next(this.users.slice());
  }

  getUsersFromRest() {
    this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('users').subscribe(
    (data: User[])=>{
      this.users = data['hydra:member'];
    });
    this.emitUsers();
  }
}
```

with in an api service

```
  public getEntriesFromRest (option: string): any {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.baseEndpoint + option);
  }
```

I know it is an rXjs operator stuff, but I did not manage to find the solution.

Comment: The wording of the question is a little confusing - are you trying to go from an Object to JSON, or from JSON to an Object?

Comment: json to Object : I make a httpRequest, and ghet the upper Json as an answer. In this Json, I have a User list and want to populate my User[] Object with this user list, but the problem is that the User list is contained under a hydra:member key

Comment: Your api returns an object not an array `this.httpClient.get<any[]>` -> `this.httpClient.get<any>`. Use the rxjs operator `map` to map the returned object to your required type. This question then becomes a pure typescript/javascript question not related to Angular or RxJS in any way. See e.g. [How to use TypeScript to map a large object to a smaller interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492930/how-to-use-typescript-to-map-a-large-object-to-a-smaller-interface)

Answer (score 2):

```
export class UserService {
  userSubject = new Subject<User[]>();
  userSubject$ = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  getUsersFromRest() {
    this.apiService
      .getEntriesFromRest("users")
      .pipe(
        map(x => JSON.stringify(x)),
        map(x => JSON.parse(x)),
        pluck("hydra:member")
      )
      .subscribe((data: User[]) => {
        this.usersSubject.next(data);
      });
  }
}
```

Can you try the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
export class UserService {

  private userSubject = new Subject<User[]>();
  userSubject$ = this.userSubject.asObservable(); // If you add a public observable of your subject, you can have other components subscribe to this, and not be able to alter the subject, but still get the data.

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  getUsersFromRest() {
    this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('users')
      .pipe(
        map((x: any) => JSON.parse(x)) // Convert your response from JSON to an Object
      .subscribe(
        (data: User[]) => {
          this.usersSubject.next(data.hydra.member);
        });
      }
  }
```

There is no need to have a separate emit users method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the userSubject for a component (Userlist) to subscribe to it... This SuerList component may also add users...
I tried implementing your method, but get errors on JSON.parse(x) : Argument of type unknow is not assignable of type string

Comment: Your other component should not alter the subject directly, it should call methods on your service to alter the userSubject. 
I've also edited my answer to fix your error.

Comment: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Answer (score 0):

I am Using Angular Cli 16
It sould better if you cast the objects from Service. After that you can manage items as you like without many poblems.

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MyObject } from './myobject';

export class MyObjectService {

  constructor(private _http : HttpClient){ }
  
  readMyObjects(): Observable<MyObjects[]>{
    return this._http.get<MyObjects[]>("http://url/to/api/");          
  }
}
...
```

[Here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-13-rxjs-observable-with-httpclient-exampleexample.html) I found a simple tutorial that explain how interact usig HttpClient.
Also on StackOverflow thera are few [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627239/casting-a-type-interface-via-map-to-observable).