# TypeScript: Extracting the parent interface proerties from a child interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose that I have a TypeScript interface Person and a subinterface Driver. I want create a new instance of Person from a Driver instance.

```
interface Person {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

interface Driver extends Person {
  driverLicense: string;
  carModel: String;
}

const johnAsDriver: Driver = {
  id: "123",
  name: "John",
  driverLicense: "ABCD-EFGH",
  carModel: "BMW"
};

// Copying "manually"
const johnAsPerson: Person = {
  id: johnAsDriver.id,
  name: johnAsDriver.name
};

console.log("Driver: ", johnAsDriver);
console.log("Person: ", johnAsPerson);
```

When I compile and run in node :

```
> tsc .\test-copy.ts 
> node .\test-copy.js
Driver:  {
  id: '123',
  name: 'John',
  driverLicense: 'ABCD-EFGH',
  carModel: 'BMW'
}
Person:  { id: '123', name: 'John' }
>
```

However, is there better way to do this? I suppose that some of [Utility methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) could be used here, but I am still confused about them. Is there some library (such as [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)) that could make this task?

Comment: Do you need it to be of *type* Person (e.g. `const johnAsPersonType: Person = johnAsDriver`) or do you need to limit the *properties* to only the ones of Person?

Comment: Are you looking for something like that tsplay.dev/w2KZxN  ? If yes, I can write an answer

Comment: Typescript won't help you here. You are either looking for some reflection mechanism so it can strip properties from object or perhaps upcasting feature. Write boilerplace code which does that for you ie `toPerson(driver: Driver)`

Comment: @captain-yossarian If the OP is looking for something like this, then I would suggest to look at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839597/typescript-extract-interface-members-only-possible) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492930/how-to-use-typescript-to-map-a-large-object-to-a-smaller-interface?rq=1) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378162/auto-skip-properties-not-belonging-to-the-type-in-typescript/) questions

Comment: @A_A you never know :D

Comment: @A_A my idea is just have the Person properties.

Comment: Actually I was waiting for something more simple, may be something like `johnAsPerson: Person = maintainJustProperties<Person>(johnAsDriver)`

Comment: Have you considered creating classes instead of interfaces? Then you could use methods to pull this data out. Driver inherits from Person but has a person method that returns the underlying person object -- the object that's created by the super call

`console.log("Driver: ", johnAsDriver);`
`console.log("Person: ", johnAsDriver.person);`

Comment: You could also give the interface some hierarchy: `Person: {id: number, name: string}`, `Driver: {person: Person, license: string, car: string}`

Comment: @Schalton unfortunatelly your suggestions don't apply in my case. :(

Comment: @RafaelAfonso I don't think you will get something simpler, than the answers of the questions I've linked earlier. There's no native function for that in typescript. On a side note: The "utility methods" you mentioned only affect types, but have no effect on the program at runtime