# Casting JSON to TS Object

Tags: json, node.js, typescript

I have some json like this;

example.json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 23,
    "country": "US",
    "language": "en",
    "created_at": 1534774253,
    "updated_at": 1534774269
}
```

And I have a user.ts interface like this;

user.ts

```
interface user {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    country: string
}
```

So, how can I cast this json to an object implemented from this interface? I tried `const userObj: user = JSON.parse(exampleJson);` but userObj has all the properties in json. I want to generate a user object that has just user.ts properties. 
For example => `JSON.stringify(userObj);`, the output is `{"id":1,"name":"John Doe","age":23,"country":"US"}`.

Anyone knows a way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me: the question is about dropping properties that aren't present in the TypeScript interface.

Comment: Where does this JSON come from? TS types imported JSON files.

Comment: @estus It's coming from a remote server via REST.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen From the accepted answer: _"You can't simple cast a plain-old-JavaScript result ... into a prototypical JavaScript/TypeScript class instance."_ + _"..., you could just do a cast to an interface (as it's purely a compile time structure)"_ -> Parse the JSON, strip the useless properties, cast to `user` (which should be named `IUser`, imho)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378742/3731501 . Also, depending on the case it may be unnecessary to get rid of unused props. That they don't exist for TS may be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript interface is a way to help giving *intellisense* (hint) to your code editor and strong typing your JSON. It doesn't have the feature to help you handle purging additional properties that you don't need. Therefore, when you do `const userObj: user = JSON.parse(exampleJson)`, you still get properties like `created_at`.

One way I think you can achieve what you need is probably writing a class.

```
class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  country: string;

  constructor(jsonString: any) {
    const userObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    // this part could be shorten with for loop
    this.id = userObj.id;
    this.name = userObj.name;
    this.age = userObj.age;
    this.country = userObj.country;
  }
}
```

Later you can use it:

```
const userObj = new User(exampleJson);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That seems the correct way to do it but I want to ask something. If my json has a lot of user object, should I create new User objects for all of them?

Comment: In that case, I assume your json is an array. You can create a user object for all of them. It's fine. Just one line That is pretty straight forward: `const userList = (JSON.parse(exampleJson)).map(x => new User(x));`

Comment: another way you can handle this is - if you know the list of properties to pick or omit, you can use something like lodash `pick` or `omit` to pick or omit addtional properties before assigning to your `userObj`.

Answer (score 0):

You create a function or preferably a file called 'valueObjects' which accepts the incoming object and then returns the desired object. Here is an example from some code I have:

```js
export const Address = ({
 Street = null,
 Street2 = null,
 City = null,
 State = null,
 ZipCode = null,
 Country = 'US',
 IsVerified = null,
 IsActive = true,
 StudentID = null,
 Description = null,
 IsPrimary = null,
 AddressID = null,
 DateCreated = null,
 DateUpdated = null
} = {}) => ({
 Street,
 Street2,
 City,
 State,
 ZipCode,
 Country,
 IsVerified,
 IsActive,
 StudentID,
 Description,
 IsPrimary,
 AddressID,
 DateCreated,
 DateUpdated
});
```

Then all you would need to do is `Address(yourObj)`